# Validação de datas

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Estou a fazer uma função de `ExcelToEntityList`, ou seja, importar os dados do Excel para uma lista, mas preciso de validar as datas de inicio e fim.

Estou a fazer da maneira correta?

A função:

```
  public List<ProdutosConfiguracaoTaxas> ExcelToEntityList(ExcelPackage package, out bool hadErrors)
    {
        hadErrors = false;
        List<ProdutosConfiguracaoTaxas> taxes = new List<ProdutosConfiguracaoTaxas>();
        ExcelWorksheet workSheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.First();
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        foreach (ExcelRangeBase firstRowCell in workSheet.Cells[1, 1, 1, workSheet.Dimension.End.Column])
        {
            table.Columns.Add(firstRowCell.Text);
        }
        for (int rowNumber = 2; rowNumber <= workSheet.Dimension.End.Row; rowNumber++)
        {
            ProdutosConfiguracaoTaxas tax = new ProdutosConfiguracaoTaxas();
            ExcelRangeBase row = workSheet.Cells[rowNumber, 1, rowNumber, workSheet.Dimension.End.Column];

            DateTime DtInicio, DtFim;

            DataRow newRow = table.NewRow();
            bool value = false;
            foreach (ExcelRangeBase cell in row)
            {
                newRow[cell.Start.Column - 1] = cell.Text;
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cell.Text))
                {
                    value = true;
                }
            }

            if (!value) { return taxes; }

            try
            {
                string dateString;

                var formats = new[] { "dd/MM/yyyy", "yyyy-MM-dd" };
                if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, formats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out DtInicio))
                {
                    tax.Data_Incio = ITCore.ExtensionsMethods.ToDateTime((string)newRow[2]);
                }
                else
                {

                }

                tax.NumeroPrestacoes = (int)newRow[0];
                tax.TAN = (int)newRow[1];


                tax.Data_Fim = ITCore.ExtensionsMethods.ToDateTime((string)newRow[3]);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                hadErrors = true;
            }

            taxes.Add(tax);
        }
        return taxes;
    }
```

Parte que estou a fazer a validação das datas:

```
        try
            {
                string dateString;

                var formats = new[] { "dd/MM/yyyy", "yyyy-MM-dd" };
                if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, formats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out DtInicio))
                {
                    tax.Data_Incio = ITCore.ExtensionsMethods.ToDateTime((string)newRow[2]);
                }
                else
                {

                }

                tax.NumeroPrestacoes = (int)newRow[0];
                tax.TAN = (int)newRow[1];


                tax.Data_Fim = ITCore.ExtensionsMethods.ToDateTime((string)newRow[3]);
            }
            catch (Exception)
```

Comment: Seria legal se você dissesse qual foi o problema que encontrou ao testar (Se deu algum erro, se simplesmente não funcionou, essas coisas). Não é muito razoável que alguém precise pegar seu código, tentar analisar de qual parte você fala, testar pra saber se tem erro, sendo que você já pode simplesmente dizer a dificuldade, não? Eu não negativei sua pergunta, mas entendo quem tenha negativado, entre outras coisas pelo que eu acabo de comentar. Tem um pessoal muito legal aqui pra ajudar, mas é bom já esclarecer a situação mais objetivamente, aí facilita pra todos.

Comment: Teste seu código se der erro poderemos te ajudar.

Comment: Ele da erro no try/catch, não deixa compilar, pois dá erro no dateString, dai querer saber se esta é a forma correta de validar as datas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Suponho que você está usando o EPPlus](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EPPlus).

Pelo que eu entendi, você está tentando jogar os dados do Excel para uma `DataTable` (porque cria `DataTables` e `DataRows` no meio disso aí), mas ao mesmo tempo cria uma lista de uma classe que recebe o dado do Excel e a retorna. É esquisito, mas podemos ajustar.

Você já está usando as funções certas. Basta entender pra que elas servem. A começar pela sua dúvida, você já fez o *parse*. Falta só atribuir:

```
            var formats = new[] { "dd/MM/yyyy", "yyyy-MM-dd" };
            if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, formats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out DtInicio))
            {
                tax.Data_Incio = DtInicio;
            }
```

`DateTime.TryParseExact` faz todo o trabalho por você e devolve dois valores:

1. Se o resultado da execução da função teve sucesso ou falha;
2. O resultado da conversão do valor de `String` para `DateTime`, na variável `DtInicio` passada por referência.

É só isso. O resto está feito. Aproveitando, vou editar um pouco seu código com algumas sugestões.

```
// Mudei o retorno porque não precisamos voltar necessariamente um List.
// Pode ser também uma Collection ou uma função geradora.
public IEnumerable<ProdutosConfiguracaoTaxas> ExcelToEntityList(ExcelPackage package, out bool hadErrors)
{
    hadErrors = false;

    // Tirei isso porque vou acumular o retorno da função, 
    // Então isto não é mais necessário.
    // var taxes = new List<ProdutosConfiguracaoTaxas>();

    var workSheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.First();

    // Não vai ser usado.
    // DataTable table = new DataTable();

    // Você está devolvendo uma lista de objetos. Não precisa povoar uma 
    // DataTable pra isso. 
    // foreach (ExcelRangeBase firstRowCell in workSheet.Cells[1, 1, 1, workSheet.Dimension.End.Column])
    // {
    //     table.Columns.Add(firstRowCell.Text);
    // }
    for (int rowNumber = 2; rowNumber <= workSheet.Dimension.End.Row; rowNumber++)
    {
        var tax = new ProdutosConfiguracaoTaxas();
        ExcelRangeBase row = workSheet.Cells[rowNumber, 1, rowNumber, workSheet.Dimension.End.Column];

        DateTime DtInicio, DtFim;

        // Isto também não precisa (já que não tem mais DataTable).
        // DataRow newRow = table.NewRow();
        bool value = false;
        foreach (ExcelRangeBase cell in row)
        {
            newRow[cell.Start.Column - 1] = cell.Text;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cell.Text))
            {
                value = true;
            }
        }

        if (!value) { return taxes; }

        try
        {
            string dateString;

            var formats = new[] { "dd/MM/yyyy", "yyyy-MM-dd" };
            if (DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, formats, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out DtInicio))
            {
                tax.Data_Incio = DtInicio;
            }
            // Tirei o else porque ele não faz nada, então não precisa existir.
            // else
            // {

            // }

            // Como não temos mais a DataRow, mudei de newRow para row.
            tax.NumeroPrestacoes = (int)row[0];
            tax.TAN = (int)row[1];

            tax.Data_Fim = ITCore.ExtensionsMethods.ToDateTime((string)row[3]);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            hadErrors = true;
        }

        // Tirei isso porque não estou mais usando a lista de Tax.
        // taxes.Add(tax);
    }

    // yield return acumula taxes no retorno. Quando o loop terminar, 
    // uma enumeração de tax será retornada. 
    yield return taxes;
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, era isto mesmo! funcionou!